# Auto redirect http site url to https in cpanel

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, cpanel

Redirect the site url http to https..for this i upload .htaccess file in my cpanl public_html root directory.the code of the file as

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sitename.in/$1 [R,L]
```

After i hosted this file also it's not redirecting my site to https protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following lines of code in the index page of the site

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
exit();
}
```

Then the site url redirected to https link

Answer (score 17):

i am writing this answer too late but currently its working fine. So try to do it on your root directory .htaccess file.

```
# Force SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** It will work only if you have `mod_rewrite` installed on cpanel server, otherwise use php bases SSL redirect.

Comment: Work great for me on .htaccess of Wordpress installation with cPanel.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I just modified the .htaccess file in the first part of the answer for my Wordpress site to redirect http:// to https://. I didn't need to modify the index page and it worked fine for me without it. Thanks to the author of that as it completed my quest for a secure certificate migration.

My complete file .htaccess file looked like this for me. I suggest making a local copy as I broke my site a few times before I found the right answer for me here:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R,L]
```